# How to consume the Socket IO to(-).emit(-) messages from client (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

In my Node JS code, the SocketIO emits will be done with room ID. Out of all room connections to Socket IO, a corresponding room will consume the particular message. Currently, I am testing this application from my local by writing a JavaScript code but I am not sure how to consume this (No issues while just using emit as I can use socket.on()). Can someone help me with this?

Below is the snippet of my Node JS code.

```
var emit = function(room, type, content) {
    io.to(room).emit("message", [type, content]);
    // send standard socket.io message with specific type, for clients connecting directly
    console.log("emit to room: '" + room + "', type: '" + type + "', content: " + content);
    return io.to(room).emit(type, content);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the client side use

```
socket.on("message",function(data)
{
//do something
})
```

To respond to the event

Comment: Hi Ellipsis, This works when I just do io.emit("message", [type, content]);  

But here I am using   io.to(room).emit("message", [type, content]); 
And I am not able to consume with the socket.on()

Comment: rooms in socket.io are created in the server internally. io.to(room) broadcasts the event in the room. All the clients in that room receive the event. This is the difference between normal broadcasting and sending an event to a specific room. But how the client/user consumes the event remains the same.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Ellipsis. This has been sorted.

Comment: If it helped you upvote and mark it as correct so that it can help others too